# Get last characters up to specific character

Tags: regex

Lets say I have a string **something-123**.

I need to get last 5 (or less) characters of it but only up to **-** if there is one in the string, so the result would be like **thing**, but if string has no **-** in it, like **something123** then the result would be **ng123**, and if string is like **123** then the result would be **123**.

I know how to mach last 5 characters:

```
/.{5}$/
```

I know how to mach everything up to first **-**:

```
/[^-]*/
```

But I can not figure out how to combine them, and to make things worse I need to get the match without extracting it from specific groups and similar advanced regex stuff because I want to use it in [SQL Anywhere](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbreference/regexp-substr-function.html), please help.

---

Tank you all for the help, but looks like a complete regex solution is going to be too complicated for my problem, so I did it very simple: `SELECT right(regexp_substr('something-123', '[^-]*'), 4)`.

Comment: What if you have `something-` as input, what is expected output for this string? `thing` or `hing-`? My solution yields `thing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
.{5}(?=(?:-[^-]*)?$)
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zD2mF0/3)

We match 5 symbols other than a newline only before the last `-` in the string or at the very end of the string (`(?=(?:-[^-]*)?$)`). You only need to collect the matches, no need checking groups/submatches.

*UPDATE*

To match any 1 to 5 characters other than a hyphen before the first hyphen (if present in the string), you can use

```
([^-]{1,5})(?:(?:-[^-]*)*)?$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wA0mP6/2). We rely on a lookahead here, that checks if there are `-`+`non-hyphen` sequences are after the expected substring.

An [faster alternative](https://regex101.com/r/wA0mP6/3):

```
^[^-]*?([^-]{1,5})(?:-|$)
```

This regex will search for any characters other than `-` up to 1 to 5 such characters.

Note that here, the value we need is in Group 1.

Comment: I changed it a bit to match up to 5 characters, so like `.{1,5}(?=(?:-[^-]*)?$)`, but it is unable to work with short strings up to 5 characters in total like **aa-bb** it maches all of it, not only **aa** as I would expect.

Comment: Could you precise if the substrings you need to match can contain `-` or not? If not, try [`([^-]{1,5})(?:-[^-]*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/wA0mP6/1).

Comment: No, I do not need the hyphen, only the characters before it if there is a hyphen in string, if there is no hyphen in string, then I need to mach last characters of the string.

Comment: Yeah, but if there are two hyphens? Also, the regex in my above comment works well with `aa-bb`. The value is in Group 1.

Comment: Do not really care, best would be to get to the last one, like if text looks like **aa-bb-cc** then match **aa-bb** (`.{1,5}(?=(?:-[^-]*)?$)` works like that now), but if it would match **aa** that would work for me. The issue I am having now is that if text is short enough, like **aa-bb** or **a-b**, then `.{1,5}(?=(?:-[^-]*)?$)` matches all of it. This is getting out of hand, didn't realize that such simple request would turn in to such complex expression...

Comment: Yes, it will, because `.` matches a `-`. If you do not want to match it, you need to use `[^-]` instead of a dot in the pattern. Check [`([^-]{1,5})(?:(?:-[^-]*)*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/wA0mP6/2).

Answer (score 2):

One option is to group the result:

```
(.{4})-
```

Now you have captured the result but without the `-`.

Or using lookarounds you can:

```
.{4}(?=-)
```

which matches any 4 characters that appears *before* "-".

Comment: `(.{4})-` matches the hyphen, `.{4}(?=-)` does not so it works as I asked, but I forgot to mention one little thing, the hyphen might not be there, then both suggested expressions mach nothing.

Comment: @Cigaras As I mentioned in my answer, the **group** **doesn't** contain the "-", you just need to extract the result from the *group* itself. How are you testing the results? What tool are you using?

Comment: http://regexr.com/, sorry, I am new to this regex stuff, and text _just need to extract the result from the group itself_ doesn't say me anything.

Comment: @Cigaras Please try the [new version](https://regex101.com/) of it, there you can see the captured group.

Comment: Not good, I am going to use this expression in [SQL Anywhere](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbreference/regexp-substr-function.html) and there are no such things as captured groups... Or I am completely lost here...

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
(.{5})(?:-[^-]+)?$
```

The result is in group 1

Comment: apolagies, I was trying to edit my answer and click yours. My bad

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
(.{1,5})(?:-.*|$)
```

Group 1 has the result you need

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/vN9xB2/10)